# Authorize.net confirmation page transaction details

Tags: php, authorize.net

Some background on what I'm doing:

I have a payment page that links to Authorize.net when users want to pay. I send the details to Authorize via "merchant fields" and also have

```
<input type='hidden' name='x_relay_url' value='https://www.mywebsite.com/success.php?type=cc'/>
```

where the success.php is the confirmation page. I am getting back to this page properly on an Authorize.net transaction. However, I am not sure how to pass the order information from Authorize.net back to this page and show the users their order details as a confirmation that it has been processed.

I have in my success.php page the following lines as well

```
$ResponseCode       = trim($_POST["x_response_code"]);
$ResponseReasonText = trim($_POST["x_response_reason_text"]);
$ResponseReasonCode = trim($_POST["x_response_reason_code"]);
$AVS                = trim($_POST["x_avs_code"]);
$TransID            = trim($_POST["x_trans_id"]);
$AuthCode           = trim($_POST["x_auth_code"]);
$Amount             = trim($_POST["x_amount"]);
```

which I'm pretty sure don't get the right information because there isn't any sort of token with my Authorize information like a "Paypal pdt token" beforehand.

Does Authorize.net also employ some sort of pdt token like Paypal that I can leverage or does it use something else entirely.

Any direction or assistance with links or code is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to develop a receipt generation page that Authorize.Net will post transaction data to when it processes a transaction.

This is what the [relay response](https://www.authorize.net/support/CNP/helpfiles/Account/Settings/Transaction_Format_Settings/Transaction_Response_Settings/Relay_Response.htm) functionality was designed for.

"With Relay Response, the payment gateway posts full transaction results to a specific Default Relay Response URL, or Web address, on your Web server. **You can use this information to create a custom transaction results page to be displayed to your customer.** The payment gateway then relays your custom transaction results page to the customer’s browser."